# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convertEntities'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, anaconda

I'm getting the error in title when trying to parse a HTML with soupparser - external interface to the BeautifulSoup HTML parser. This is my code:

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
fromstring("<html><body></body></html>");
```

Also, since I'm using Anaconda's Python distribution, I loaded BeautifulSoup like this:

```
import sys, bs4
sys.modules['BeautifulSoup'] = bs4
```

Error I'm getting is: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convertEntities'` when soupparser calls bs4 with:

```
if 'convertEntities' not in bsargs:
  bsargs['convertEntities'] = 'html'
  tree = beautifulsoup(source, **bsargs)
```

Also, first time I run it within IPython notebook, I get the following warning:

```
.../python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py:88: UserWarning: BS4 does not respect the convertEntities argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor. Entities are always converted to Unicode characters.
```

Comment: What `lxml` version do you have installed?

Comment: When I type in conda search lxml, the star (*) is on 3.4.2 and the dot (.) is at 3.4.0

Comment: The * is the one that you have installed.